# Get UserControl ControlID from within ASCX

Tags: asp.net, properties, user-controls

I have a data source on a web page with the declaration below. It is using a property from the page as filter.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsMyDataSource"
TypeName="Game" SelectMethod="GetBySomeID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SomeID" ControlID="__Page" Type="Int32"
        PropertyName="MyID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

A repeater is attached to this data source.
Now, I would like to move this repeater and its data source into a user control (ASCX). The MyID property will also be moved from the ASPX to the ASCX. What I don't know here is what to use as ControlID inside the asp:ControlParameter instead of __Page.

Comment: Are you registering the ASCX more than once or only once? If you are registering the ASCX only once you can use the ID of user control defined on Page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent treatment of exactly this situation:   [ControlParameter Supports "_*Page" as ControlId, But Not "*_UserControl"](http://www.governor.co.uk/news-plus-views/2009/february/controlparameter-supports-%E2%80%9C__page%E2%80%9D-as-controlid,-but-not-%E2%80%9C__usercontrol%E2%80%9D/).  There are quite a few ways to handle it; this article lists a few.

Comment: @Ann_L. Thanks! I had already seen this page when I googled for a solution, but I was hoping there would be a simpler solution without having to add some code behind. Oh, well, I'll use the first solution proposed on that page. All this Microsoft Asp.Net stuff is not really making our lives simpler. It is just displacing the difficulties elsewhere. My opinion...

Comment: Have you tried using the user control's own ID as the ControlID?  (I assume you have, but thought I'd ask.)  I don't know if that would work, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @AnnL. Is there a new link? The link above returns 404.

Comment: @athoik  There doesn't seem to be, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

On Page let's assume that we are registering a user control and we are using it **only once**.

```
<%@ Register Src="user_control.ascx" TagName="my_user_control" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:my_user_control ID="my_user_control1" runat="server" />
```

Then inside the control we can use the ID `my_user_control1`.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="SomeID" ControlID="my_user_control1" Type="Int32" PropertyName="MyID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I found is to create a new control inside your user control, and hide it, like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStartDate" Text='<%= this.StartDate %>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dsData" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetDataStoredProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblStartDate" Name="startDate" PropertyName="text" DbType="DateTime" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and in the code behind of the user control:

```
 public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return ViewState["StartDate"] != null ? (DateTime)ViewState["StartDate"] : DateTime.Now; }
        set { ViewState["StartDate"] = value; }
    }
```